# Sqlite-icu for windows

Tags: python, c, windows, sqlite

I know questions like this have been asked a lot (and trust me in the past several weeks i have read everything i could find) but i cannot find a way to use the sqlite-icu extension for python 3 on Windows.It works flawlessly on linux (like a lot of the things i tried). I obviously tried installing tru pip and that failed. I tried different python and pip versions and that failed, so i looked up into the error and the setup.py of the pip package and found out it fails bc i don't have pkg-config on my machine. That is all fine but i don't know shit about libraries on windows. On linux it is easy, you just apt install what you need and when you need to compile something it just works. I tried manually compiling the extension on windows and i got a .dll file (2 actually one using cygwin and one with msys.) but when i try to load them in python i get an Error:
"sqlite3.OperationalError: The specified procedure could not be found."

Btw compiling it using gcc on linux and then loading the .so (on my linux machine) works flawlessly. I think like with a lot of python extensions coded in C i should compile it using MSVC but i cannot find a way to make that work.

If anybody knows how to do it pls help me or if you have compiled it before pls share the dll file with me. At this point i am so desperate i would literally load any .dll file you give me as long as it works. Thank you to anybody who read thru and even more to anybody chimes in!

Answer (score 1):

I would compile SQLite with ICU integrated. To do it on Windows with MSVC, you need several tools:

- MSVC Build Tools
- Windows Resource Kit
- ICU4C binaries (icu4c-VV-WinXX-MSVCyyyy.zip, e.g., icu4c-70_1-Win64-MSVC2019.zip)
  Set USE_ICU=1 and add (ARCH is equal to 64 for x64 and "" for x32; ICU_HOME - path to the top folder containing extracted archive [spaces are not allowed in this path])

  - %ICU_HOME%\bin%ARCH% to PATH
  - %ICU_HOME%\lib%ARCH% to LIB
  - %ICU_HOME%\include to INCLUDE
- TCL (add TCL\bin folder in the Path)

Download the canonical SQLite source distribution and extract it. Start Build Tools shell, enter the *sqlite* folder with sources and *make* files. Set/add variables as indicated above and do `nmake /f Makefile.msc all`. You can verify your dev settings before building by running this code:

```
@echo off
:: ============================================================================
:: Collects MSVC environment information.
:: ===========================================================================

:: ================================ BEGIN MAIN ================================
:MAIN
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set STDOUTLOG=stdout.log
set STDERRLOG=stderr.log
del "%STDOUTLOG%" 2>nul
del "%STDERRLOG%" 2>nul


(
  echo ======================= SHELL SETTINGS ======================
  echo =============================================================
  echo  DESIRED VALUES:
  echo     EnableExtensions    REG_DWORD    0x1
  echo     DelayedExpansion    REG_DWORD    0x1
  echo.
  echo  ACTUAL  VALUES:
  reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /s /f nsion
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  echo.

  echo ================== CHECKING MSVC VARIABLES ==================
  echo =============================================================
  set ErrorStatus=0
  call :CHECKVAR "VisualStudioVersion" "%VisualStudioVersion%"
  call :CHECKVAR "VSINSTALLDIR" "%VSINSTALLDIR%"
  call :CHECKVAR "VCINSTALLDIR" "%VCINSTALLDIR%"
  call :CHECKVAR "VCToolsInstallDir" "%VCToolsInstallDir%"
  call :CHECKVAR "VCToolsVersion" "%VCToolsVersion%"
  call :CHECKVAR "VSCMD_ARG_HOST_ARCH" "%VSCMD_ARG_HOST_ARCH%"
  call :CHECKVAR "VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH" "%VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH%"
  call :CHECKVAR "VSCMD_VER" "%VSCMD_VER%"
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  call :CHECKERRORSTATUS "MSVC VARIABLES"
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  echo.

  echo ==================== CHECKING MSVC TOOLS ====================
  echo =============================================================
  set ErrorStatus=0
  call :CHECKTOOL cl
  call :CHECKTOOL nmake
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  call :CHECKERRORSTATUS "MSVC TOOLS"
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  echo.

  echo ======================= CHECKING TCL ========================
  echo =============================================================
  set ErrorStatus=0
  call :CHECKTOOL tclsh "%TCL_HOME%\bin"
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  call :CHECKERRORSTATUS "TCL"
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  echo.

  echo ======================= CHECKING ICU ========================
  echo =============================================================
  set ErrorStatus=0
  call :CHECKTOOL uconv "%ICU_HOME%\bin"
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  call :CHECKERRORSTATUS "ICU"
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  echo.

  echo ============== CHECKING WINDOWS RESOURCE KITS ===============
  echo =============================================================
  set ErrorStatus=0
  call :CHECKSUBSTRING "INCLUDE" "%INCLUDE%" "Windows Kits"
  call :CHECKSUBSTRING "LIB"     "%LIB%"     "Windows Kits"
  call :CHECKSUBSTRING "LIBPATH" "%LIBPATH%" "Windows Kits"
  call :CHECKSUBSTRING "Path"    "%Path%"    "Windows Kits"
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  call :CHECKERRORSTATUS "WINDOWS RESOURCE KITS"
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  echo.
) 1>>"%STDOUTLOG%" 2>>"%STDERRLOG%"


EndLocal
exit /b 0
:: ================================= END MAIN =================================


:: ============================================================================
:CHECKVAR
:: Call this sub with argument(s):
::   - %1 - Variable name
::   - %2 - Variable value
::
set VarName=%~1
set VarValue=%~2
if "/%VarValue%/"=="//" (
  set ErrorStatus=1
  echo %%%VarName%%% not set.
) else (
  echo %VarName%=%VarValue%
)

exit /b 0


:: ============================================================================
:CHECKTOOL
:: Call this sub with argument(s):
::   - %1 - Tool executable name
::   - %2 - CD before check
::
set CurDir=%CD%
if exist "%~2" cd /d "%~2"
set CommandText=where "%~1"
set Output=
for /f "Usebackq delims=" %%i in (`%CommandText%`) do (
  if "/!Output!/"=="//" (
    set Output=%%i
  )
)
cd /d "%CurDir%"

if "/%Output%/"=="//" (
  set ErrorStatus=1
  echo "%~1" not found.
) else (
  echo %~1=%Output%
)

exit /b 0


:: ============================================================================
:CHECKSUBSTRING
:: Call this sub with argument(s):
::   - %1 - Variable name
::   - %2 - Variable value
::   - %3 - Substring
::
set VarName=%~1
set VarValue=_%~2_
set Substring=%~3

set TestString=!VarValue:%Substring%=!
if "/%TestString%/"=="/%VarValue%/" (
  set ErrorStatus=1
  echo "%VarName%" does not contain %Substring%.
) else (
  echo "%VarName%" - match found.
)

exit /b 0


:: ============================================================================
:CHECKERRORSTATUS
:: Call this sub with argument(s):
::   - %1 - Test name
::
if %ErrorStatus% NEQ 0 (
  echo #################### Test %~1 failed. ####################
) else (
  echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Test %~1 passed. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
)

exit /b 0
```

Check out this [resource](https://pchemguy.github.io/SQLite-ICU-MinGW/) for additional documentation and build scripts. You could also ask for binaries by opening an issue in the repo.